# Why not every keyup value is being hold on the input even tho is being passed as parameter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this strange issue, I assume it’s something about processing time, I have a PIN with 4 inputs. You can actually see it on this stackblitz code I prepared:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fezgmd?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Just check these 2 function: **nextInput** and **handleKeyUp** // I left the rest of the code to enable the whole functionality and don't crash things.

If everything is fine ⇒ handleKeyUp will execute nextInput and pass a param called key which is basically the key pressed.
nextInput does this:

```
    const nextInput = (key: string): void => {
      console.log(key)
      if (
        focusOn.value !== null &&
        focusOn.value < props.length - 1
      ) {
        code[focusOn.value] = key
        inputs[focusOn.value + 1].focus()
        }
```

> focusOn.value => index
>
> code => reactive object[Array] bind to the v-model input

So the idea is assigning the key value to the input BUT sometimes (mostly when u type fast) the console.log(key) will show the key pressed but the input not holding the value, like this:
[image]

You can see the 5 in the console, which is from the console.log(key) in nextInput function, but you don't see the last input holding that value.

I already tried different conditionals, but it's not working, I just don't get it. Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: *check these 2 function: nextInput and handleKeyUp* - you only show one function, and there's nothing changing `focusOn.value` so can't see how anything but the first field could have a value

Comment: I left the code on a stackblitz link

Comment: You should put the relevant code on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is here in `nextInput()`

```js
if (focusOn.value !== null && focusOn.value < props.length - 1)
```

On the last keyup, `focusOn.value` equals 3 and `props.length - 1` also equals 3, so you don't enter inside the if and you don't run this line assigning to the `code` array:

```js
code[focusOn.value] = key;
```

Since the if statement is only to decide whether to focus the next input, this line can safely go above the if:

```js
const nextInput = (key: string): void => {
      code[focusOn.value] = key;
      if (focusOn.value !== null && focusOn.value < props.length - 1) {
        inputs[focusOn.value + 1].focus();
      }
    };
```

The reason it only happens when typing fast is because you're actually pressing multiple keys at the same time (rolling your fingers across the keys will do this) so at the end you're getting multiple keyups without keydowns, whereas when you're typing slow the last input's v-model is actually handling the value assignment.